# Color the lines of a table in red

Tags: html, css, powershell

Here is my script:

```
 function f_Mail($t) 
 {
     $from="***"
     $to="***"
     $subject="test"
         $body = '<font face ="segoe ui,calibri,verdana" size = "-1">' + $body + '</font>'
         $body += "<HTML><BODY><Table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 width=70% id=Header>"
         $body += "<p><br>Bonjour,<br><br>  Vous trouverez ci joint un rapport de sauvegarde des serveurs d'impréssions et
                   des serveurs *** **** </p>"
         $body += "<TR>
                   <TH><B><U><font color=""#5f9ea0"">Nom</font></U></B></TH>
                   <TH><B><U><font color=""#5f9ea0"">Date</font></U></B></TH>
                   <TH><B><U><font color=""#5f9ea0"">Sauvegarde</font></U></B></TH>
                   </TR>"     
         Foreach($o in $t)
             {
                 $body +="<TR><TD>$($o.nom )</TD>
                          <TD>$($o.date)</TD>
                          <TD>$($o.sauvegarde)</TD></TR>" 

             }
          $body += "</table>"
          $body += '<br><br><font face ="segoe ui,calibri,verdana" size = "-1.5"><b>' + "*****<br> Direction des Systèmes  
                    d'Information<br>Service Infrastructures et Exploitation<br> *******" + '</b></font>'
             Send-MailMessage -from $from 
                              -to $to 
                              -subject $subject 
                              -body $body -BodyAsHtml 
                              -smtpServer ****** 
                              -Encoding UTF8}

$date = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd" $rep="c:\test" $files=
Get-ChildItem $rep\* -Include *.zip,*printerExport -Recurse |Select
 Name, @{Name="LastWriteTime";
 Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}}  $t_obj = @()
 $date_formatee_ordi = $date $tt=Get-Date -UFormat %A
 if($tt -eq $tt){#check les deux fichier a changer en jeudi apres
    foreach($item in $files){
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        #$time = $item.LastWriteTime
        $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                            -name "nom" 
                           -value $item.Name 

        $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                           -name "date" 
                           -value $item.LastWriteTime
                    if( $item.LastWriteTime -eq $date_formatee_ordi)
                    {   
                            $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                                       -name "sauvegarde" 
                                       -value $true
                    }
                 else
                 {        
                            $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                                -name "sauvegarde" 
                                -value $false # i ***think it is necessary to c   add code but i don't know what 
                   }***
              $t_obj += $obj
               $obj = $null
           }
    }
    else{#bcdi
        $choix="bcdi"
        $files= get-childitem C:\test\$choix| Select Name, @{Name="LastWriteTime";
        Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}} 
        $t_obj = @()
             foreach($item in $files)
                {
                     $obj = New-Object PSObject
                     #$time = $item.LastWriteTime
                        $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                                     -name "nom" 
                                  -value $item.Name 

                    $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                               -name "date" 
                               -value $item.LastWriteTime
                 if( $item.LastWriteTime -eq $date_formatee_ordi)
                     {   
                         $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                                           -name "sauvegarde" 
                                           -value $true
                      }
                  else
                  {        
                      $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty 
                                 -name "sauvegarde" 
                                 -value $false
                  }
     $t_obj += $obj
     $obj = $null
 }} f_Mail $t_obj
```

This is what it returns on Outlook:

[image: Screenshot]

Can you tell me how it is possible to color all lines `False` in red?

Comment: Script is in very much scrambled shape. Why dont you do one thing. Copy the script and paste in pastebin or github and share the link with us. May be then we can sort it out. Or else select the entire script and paste it in the script block of stackoverflow.

Comment: Please disregard the comment above. Keep all relevant information in your question (and as concise as possible). Do *not* post relevant parts of your question on external resources.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of posting answers that don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the table rows depending on the value of `$o.sauvegarde`.

Change this:

```
$body += "<TR><TD>$($o.nom )</TD>
         <TD>$($o.date)</TD>
         <TD>$($o.sauvegarde)</TD></TR>"
```

into something like this:

```
$body += if ($o.sauvegarde) {
    '<TR>'
} else {
    '<TR style="color: #ff0000;">'
}
$body += "<TD>$($o.nom)</TD><TD>$($o.date)</TD><TD>$($o.sauvegarde)</TD></TR>"
```